# Why Quartz 2.* does not cleanup indexes in Postgres database?

Tags: java, postgresql, indexing, quartz-scheduler

I use Quartz 2.* in cluster mode. Quartz uses Postgres database for clustering feature. Database size grows as the Java application works. The only reason for this growing is that Quartz does not cleanup it's indexes on tables:

```
quartz.qrtz_triggers
quartz.qrtz_cron_triggers
quartz.qrtz_fired_triggers
quartz.qrtz_scheduler_state
```

One week of application working increases database by ~500 MiB. I have 5 microservices which use Quartz, so the whole database grows by 5*500 MiB each week.

Then I need to execute manually:

```
REINDEX TABLE quartz.qrtz_cron_triggers;
REINDEX TABLE quartz.qrtz_fired_triggers;
REINDEX TABLE quartz.qrtz_triggers;
REINDEX TABLE quartz.qrtz_scheduler_state;
```

And after it the database's size becomes adequate.

Is it normal?

How to configure Quartz/Postgres to cleanup it's stuff atomatically?

Comment: Did you disable autovacuum in Postgres?

Comment: No. As far as I see, the VACUUM processes run on host with database. And also when I executed VACUUM manually it has not stripped indexes

Comment: Then the auto vacuum daemon can't cleanup the indexes. Check if you have a lot of connections that are `idle in transaction`. If you do, try to configure the connection pool to physically close them, so that Postgres can properly cleanup.

Comment: So the auto vacuum is responsible for cleanup indexes? Thanks for your answer, I`ll try to check this.

Comment: I've checked that there is only one "idle in transaction" to databaseX. May it distract the auto vacuuming in databaseY if they run on the same Postgres server?

Comment: If it has the table rows in use, hasn't committed, or some other scenarios, it could have the table hung in such a way that PG cannot vacuum them. You can try manually vacuuming to see if you get errors to give you more details.

Comment: I've got Postgres 9.5.

Manual VACUUM does not shrink indexes.
Manual VACUUM FULL does.

As far as I understand, autovacuum does not perform VACUUM FULL. So there is no reason why I have to tune autovacuum feature.

Comment: Is this just normal bloat, and what's so particular about Quartz's usage that it can get this high? The tables certainly have a lot of indexes, but still a `60MB` table taking up `1,5GB` of disk space seems excessive.

Comment: please specify what indexes you have? In fact table definition as well. please specify how much the table bloats, if 5 indexes grow 500 MB in a week - what is table growth? please show the last_vacuum and last_autovacuum from `pg_stat_all_tables` for the table. you have one `idle in transaction` what are others?.. `active`?.. how many? Please choose one db and isolate results for it only. If problem is general - other dbs will fix as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not being that experienced with the quartz / postgres combination, this seems to be an index fragmentation problem.

I.e. index size grows and performance suffers while table rows are being updated or deleted repeatedly. This could be the case if your quartz jobs run in short intervals while creating a corresponding number of entries in your cluster database.

Reindexing the database tables (a common maintenance procedure) refreshes the index and potentially reduces the index size also.
I would propose to create a database job running the reindexing commands on a regular basis, from what i found this can be done using either the pg_cron or pgAdmin tool.

You will also find some useful queries regarding index size/usage and index bloat in the PostgreSQL Wiki:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance

Comment: Indeed, it seems that quartz's index heavy (actually I'd say excessive) schema and certain particular workloads (high update count) can easily cause this if not taken care of. In my case as the row counts of the tables were minute (< 10), the indexes were only slowing things down. As a solution I removed the indexes completely (they weren't being used anyway), therefore improving the update time and removing index bloat. I see this mainly as a Quartz "incompatibility" with Postgres, due to the overeager index creation. Have some bounty for your trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! ;-) I also would think the best solution in this case is to remove the indexes completely. Normally the optimizer will choose a full table scan anyway if row number is that small.